# Where to declare a function to optimize ES6 class usage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization, webpack

I am developing some web-app using React, just so that anybody reading can understand what is going on. That said, this is essentially a question regarding **ES6 code optimization**, rather then React and what have you.

> **TL;DR:**   I know that it reeeeeally won't make any goddamn difference because of how simple the whole thing is, but I am
>   wondering, in theory, what is the best approach? What is the 'good
>   practice' standard for declaring functions to be used within ES6 class
>   methods with most performance optimization?

What would be the most optimal place to define a "helper" function which is used by one of the methods of my class, for example:

```
class Table extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.instanceBasedFilter = function(){...}    // Option 1
    }
    state = {};
    render() {
        const { filterProp } = this.props;
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <table>
                    {this.filterMethod(filterProp)}
                </table>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
    prototypeBasedFilter(){...}    // Option 2
    filterMethod = filter => {
        filter = filter || [];
        function methodBasedFilter(){...}    // Option 3
        filter.filter(/* need to pass a function here*/)
    };
}
function outsideBasedFilter(){...}    // Option 4
```

So obviously, they are all different, overhead cannot be avoided in this case, I am just wondering which would be considered the best approach. For argument's sake lets disregard the option of placing a filter helper inside a different .js file, let's say that it is specific to this component.

My view on the options is bellow, correct me if I am wrong and suggest an option that is best practice if you know one.

**Option 1:**
A function object will be created every time the component is created and attached to the DOM, this can result in a moderate amount of "creations". On the plus side though, it will only take up memory space for as long as the component is displayed, once removed, memory is freed up, if I understand garbage collector properly.

**Option 2:**
A single function object will be created for use with all the components, so the processing is done only once, however it will be kept in memory for as long as the application runs.

**Option 3:**
A function object will be created every time the component updates, this can really end up being a lot of times, on the plus side though, as soon as the rendering is done, the memory is freed up, this options is what I'd intuitively go for if I was not thinking about optimizing, because i'd just inline an arrow function and be done with it. But it is the most overhead, no?

**Option 4:**
Now honestly this one has me most wound up... since I cannot demystify how it gets compiled. Placing a function declaration outside of the class itself exposes it to that class, and it's prototype, but I have no clue how does webpack/babel compile it. I'd make an educated guess that it is similar to option two in terms of optimization, since I'd assume its "held in scope" of some anonymous function that denotes a module environment, which means so long as the app is running it will never be collected, but also it will only be defined once.

So best practice?

Comment: Your introductory statement is correct: it doesn't matter for 99% of all applications. If you're right on the edge of modern JavaScript performance capacity, there are a whole lot of other things to know as well, and going back to the basics of computer science your algorithmic and data structure optimizations are almost certainly *vastly* more important than tiny micro-optimizations of any sort.

Comment: Unless you *really really need* to conserve memory, options 2 and 4 (a single function stays in memory as long as the `Table` class exists) make much more sense than the rest IMO. Re-declaring an identical function for every new component (or render) is wasteful.

Comment: @Pointy It is just a thing that started becoming an issue for me in the projects since eslint was configured to allow for a maximum of 2 levels of nested functions, essentially making option #3 impossible, and when discussing with the proj. manager, the "it is more optimized that way" was the reasoning, so I am wondering, what is the tradeoff that we are getting here. I understand that it is essentially ProcessingPower vs Memory, but fail to grasp which one is more important, in javascript, particularly, or in this type of scenario. Everybody is all "performance performance" these days.

Comment: @CertainPerformance then i'd opt for option 4 since I wouldn't want to pollute the object's prototype and/or expose the function for 'fiddling/changing' on the said object.

Comment: @CertainPerformance note that "re-declaring" a function just means that the Function instance needs to be created; the *code* for the function is only parsed once and can be shared by all instances because it's immutable. It's really not that expensive.

Comment: If this question is about performance optimisation: if it matters for you - measure (that's the only valid answer in every question about performance optimisations).

Comment: @Dellirium well I'll just repeat what I wrote already: your algorithmic approach to a problem is way, way more important than little details like this. Also don't let ESLint rule your life; it's an extremely opinionated tool that is fine for some perspective but don't be its slave.

Comment: @Pointy I thought every new declaration of a function created a separate one? Eg `for (..) { const fn = () => 'foo }` creates a new function for every iteration, it's not shared? (similarly, for options 1 and 3, a new function on every constructor call or `filterMethod` call?) Every new function won't be `===` to another

Comment: @zerkms I am assuming that any form of testing will be absolutely impossible until this application becomes more robust, cannot imagine that some bytes or minor processing would yield any results that can govern dicisions. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @CertainPerformance it does, but how expensive is `var x = {};`? Making a new Function object can't be much different from that when the runtime knows to associate the function object with whatever internal "blob of code" object the runtime maintains for every function body. The *code* is shared, even though the function objects themselves are distinct. (Note that scope determination is relatively static; no matter how many instances there are, the aggregate scope chain is the same for each one as it's determined by lexical structure.)

Comment: "that some bytes or minor processing would yield any results that can govern dicisions" --- you're right, so what your question is about then?

Comment: Theoretical, more then anything else really. I'd like to write properly though, if there is a common "this was proven to be better" case. But seems there isn't and proj. manager just likes to limit us with meaningless eslint rules.

Comment: Performance optimisation is unique to every case, advices about performance optimisations don't scale. Unless you measure yourself it's impossible to say whether a particular decision is "better" or "worse" than anything else